# image style depend on taxonomy term drupal 7 on a view

Tags: image, drupal-7, view, user-profile

i have a view to list all users in the site ,i want to change the user picture display style depending on the users's category(which is a taxonomy term) i have tried to add CSS class to the picture with the name of the category(via rewrite field) but that will re-size image on the fly and this will first increase load time second image may be pixeled any suggestions on how to make this available .

Comment: why don't you ask this on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only suggest [creating a PHP field](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/03/10/drupal-7-add-php-field-to-view/) and have a condition there.

Comment: first thanks for your reply and your time.second ,this will not allow me to change the image style that re-size the image ,i think this will only allow me to add css class to the image which i already do with the rewrite field option.thanks again

Comment: No, waht I had in mind is rendering your image within PHP field, no CSS classes required. You just have an `if` condition that checks your taxonomy type and `theme_image_style(...)` for each of the styles you need to render.

Comment: thanks again,i will now search how to use the theme_image_style () thanks again :)

Comment: thanks i have tried this yesterday and it works for me but i got some Notices  Trying to get property of non-object,Undefined property but this did not effect the solution and i will find way to solve them thanks again and i  will post complete solution .